# Youtube xml feed is down

Tags: xml, video, youtube, feed

I have since yesterday the XML stream Youtube videos is down, do you have the same problem?
thank you

Example : please click

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/jojol67/uploads?alt=rss&v=2&orderby=published&client=ytapi-youtube-profile.xml

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be addressed to youtube

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this blogpost](http://youtube-eng.blogspot.de/2015/04/bye-bye-youtube-data-api-v2.html), v2 is **not available anymore**. It looks like you are using v2 because of the gdata.youtube.com in your links.

Here are the 2 new Youtube RSS feed structure that you will need for Youtube video syndication and to pull videos into RSS readers.

1. Channel ID - https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=YOURCHANNELID
   Replace YOURCHANNELID with your Youtube channels ID number.
2. Username - https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?user=USERNAME
   Replace USERNAME with your Youtube username.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Sameer! I edited your post to include the actual link (and changed the link to point to the *actual* article, and not the blog start page).